# Generating syntax for a method signature from a method symbol in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm trying to generate code using Roslyn (first time user). I'm finding it so verbose that I can only assume I'm doing something wrong. At the moment I'm generating an implementation of a method for a given `IMethodSymbol` (which came from an interface):

```
private static MethodDeclarationSyntax GetMethodDeclarationSyntax(IMethodSymbol methodSymbol)
{
    if (methodSymbol.MethodKind != MethodKind.Ordinary)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var parameters = methodSymbol
        .Parameters
        .Select(x => SF
            .Parameter(SF.Identifier(x.Name))
            .WithType(SF.IdentifierName(x.Type.ToDisplayString(symbolDisplayFormat))));

    return SF
        .MethodDeclaration(
            SF.IdentifierName(methodSymbol.ReturnType.ToDisplayString(symbolDisplayFormat)),
            SF.Identifier(methodSymbol.Name))
        .WithModifiers(
            SF.TokenList(
                SF.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
        .WithParameterList(
            SF.ParameterList(
                SF.SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(parameters)));
}
```

It's already pretty hefty and I haven't accounted for the actual implementation, generic parameters, `ref`/`out` parameters etcetera.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of VS 2015 CTP 6 and the Roslyn 1.0-rc1 NuGet packages, take a look at the [`SyntaxGenerator` class](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Editing/SyntaxGenerator.cs,3c40e627ffcd3bf7).

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I'll take a look at `SyntaxGenerator`. Would you mind taking a look at this question too? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84932/using-roslyn-to-find-interfaces-within-a-solution

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see how I can use `SyntaxGenerator` with my current design because I have separated workspace creation from code generation. The code generation piece no longer has a `Document` or `Workspace` with which to create the `SyntaxGenerator`. It's likely I'm Doing It Wrong™

Comment: Well, `Workspace` layer is where helpful services like this tend to live.  The compiler level APIs are intended to be the raw building blocks, so it's *possible* to do it the way you are doing, but you asked for an easier way - that easier way is in the higher layers of abstraction.

Comment: yeah, I refactored my code so that I could use the `SyntaxGenerator`. It's definitely made the codegen logic a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Given [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268318/5380), this is what I arrived at:

```
var methodDeclaration = syntaxGenerator.MethodDeclaration(methodSymbol);
methodDeclaration = syntaxGenerator
    .WithModifiers(
        methodDeclaration,
        syntaxGenerator
            .GetModifiers(methodDeclaration)
            .WithIsAbstract(false));
methodDeclaration = syntaxGenerator
    .WithStatements(
        methodDeclaration,
        GetMethodStatementsSyntax(syntaxGenerator, semanticModel, methodSymbol));
```

Notice we have to manually remove the `abstract` modifier from the method symbol (since it originated from an interface, it is intrinsically `abstract`). I also add the statements *after* removing the `abstract` modifier because otherwise they're ignored.